# how to configure drupal settings to be available to visualize the available variables?

Tags: configuration

how must drupal local settings be configured to display available variables using IDEs or other tools ?

I guess this is xdebug and phpstorm but i don't know how to configure it if i don't have full admin access to the server.

[image]

Comment: You normally use this only locally.

Comment: You don't need to change any Drupal settings. Xdebug is a PHP extension which might be already installed on your server or you are allowed to enable and configure PHP extensions yourself. But this is off-topic here.

Comment: @4k4 Could it be imagined as a feature of devel module? an in-place x-debug like tool ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use kint which will print you all the variables

https://www.webwash.net/how-to-print-variables-using-kint-in-drupal-8/

or dpm (in devel module)

https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/devel/dpm-and-other-devel-functions

Comment: i am trying to find more efficient alternatives to dpm or kint

Comment: normally, you will use xdebug on local machine, it might be a bit tricky to setup remote debugging